# How to binding slider.value to ellipse gradient startpoint

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, blend

how to adjust the color using the slider???

like this

http://s2.ipicture.ru/uploads/20140220/4q71sUT5.jpg

http://s4.postimg.org/43lecgnjx/Bind.jpg

Answer (score 2):

```
<StackPanel>
    <Ellipse x:Name="ell" Width="50" Height="50">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop x:Name="stopToBind" Color="#FFFF0808" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>

    <Slider Value="{Binding ElementName=stopToBind, Path=Offset, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**UPDATE**

Without smooth:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Ellipse x:Name="ell" Width="50" Height="50">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="{Binding ElementName=sl, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="{Binding ElementName=sl, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>

    </Ellipse>

    <Slider Value="0.5" x:Name="sl" Maximum="1" Minimum="0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply, but I need that would border between colors was not blurred

Comment: Thank you very much! And one more question and I can manage it from the code without using the slider, through the variables?

Comment: I think it's enough for another question :p